# How to return a value from a nested function into main script in Julia?

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

For example:

function main()

```
function doit()
    A = ones(Int, 2) 
    return A
end

doit()
display(A) 
A = [1, 2, 3] 
display(A)
doit()
display(A)
```

Also what if the nested function has two or three layers, how can we return local variable values into main or save them into main?

Comment: Hi, It is very hard to understand the question without a bit more details :) could you elaborate a bit, or make the example clearer? 
If I understood you could add a return statement for each nested function to return the value to the outer one until you are out of all of them

Answer (score 0):

Functions in introduce ha hard scope so normally variables defined within them are not seen outside.
For your case I understand that you want the function `doit()` have an external effect of mutating a global variable.

While the use of global variables is discouraged and such side effects are generally not elegant pattern, it can be easily achieved by using `global` keyword:

```
function doit()
    global A = ones(Int, 2) 
    return A
end
```

in that case your Julia session could look like:

```
julia> doit();

julia> display(A)
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1

julia> A = [1,2,3];

julia> doit();

julia> display(A)
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1
```

For more information, you need to have a look now variable scoping works in Julia: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/